# Struct Pointer in C initialised only the first pointer with NULL and 0

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, doubly-linked-list, function-declaration

I have a struct for a Double List with next and prev pointers. I'm trying to create a second list where I'm putting the fruits with odd number of calories from the first list. But I don't know why, when the second list enters in the append function, after I set the first and last pointers to NULL, only the first pointer is still set on NULL, the last pointer being uninitialised.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct DoubleList DoubleList;
typedef struct Fruit Fruit;

struct Fruit {
    char* name;
    int calories;
};

struct Node {
    Fruit info;
    Node* next, * prev;
};

struct DoubleList {
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
};

void append(DoubleList* list, Fruit f) {
    Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->info = f;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;

    if (list->last) {
        list->last->next = new;
        list->last = new;
    }
    else {
        list->last = list->first = new;
    }
}

void main() {
    DoubleList ld;

    ld.first = NULL;
    ld.last = NULL;

    append(&ld, createFruit("Avocado", 201));
    append(&ld, createFruit("Apple", 251));
    append(&ld, createFruit("Strawberries", 100));
    append(&ld, createFruit("Cherry", 50));

    DoubleList* ld2 = (DoubleList*)malloc(sizeof(DoubleList));
    //DoubleList ld2;
    ld2->first = NULL;
    ld2->last = NULL;
    Node* temp = ld.first;

    while (temp)
    {
        Node* aux = temp->next;
        if (temp->info.calories % 2 == 1) {
            append(&ld2, temp->info); 
            //but I don't know why this line won't send the list to the append function with the pointers set on NULL
            //append(ld2, temp->info); this line is working

        }
        else {
            free(temp->info.name);
            free(temp);
        }
        temp = aux;
    }
    show(*ld2);
}
```

[image: Before entering in the append function]

[image: After entering in the append function]

Comment: I would not use "new" as an identifier in a context which you tagged "C++".

Comment: Edit queue is full - Please don't tag both [C] and [C++] as your question says [C] in the title.  The [C++] answer is a re-write to [C++]

Comment: `ld2` is a pointer, so `&ld2` creates a pointer to a pointer. Not what `append` expects. (Also, this is definitely C and not valid as  C++).

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah, sorry, I just translated the code to English

Comment: Stop wasting time chasing bugs that the compiler has already found. Your code is invalid C, configure your compiler correctly and it will tell you as much: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1):

The function append is declared like:

```
void append(DoubleList* list, Fruit f);
```

That is, its first parameter has the type `DoubleList *`.

The variable ld2 is declared as having the same type `DoubleList *`:

```
DoubleList* ld2 = (DoubleList*)malloc(sizeof(DoubleList));
```

But you are calling the function append passing to the function a pointer to the pointer ld2:

```
append(&ld2, temp->info);
```

So the argument type is not compatible with the parameter type.

Also, the while loop leaves the source list `ld` in an indeterminate state.

Pay attention to the fact that, according to the C Standard, the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like:

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: I get that, but why the first pointer save the NULL state and the last pointer is uninitialised when working with the pointer to the pointer?

Comment: @Foreastbtch In this case the function has undefined behavior.